# How to access object property dynamically by variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to send data to a controller and retrieve it. When I have `console.log(result.ans2.pass)` it works.

However with `console.log(result.ans + x + .pass)` It keeps given me an error:

> expected expression, got '.'

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://some-url',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    datasent: dataKey
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    var x = 2;
    console.log(result.ans + x + .pass)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically add to a variable name like you're trying to do with [*dot notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation). Instead, you can use [*bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) and concatenation so that you can access your property name using a string:

```
console.log(result["ans"+x].pass)
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the property of an object using a string you need to use bracket notation:

```
console.log(result['ans' + x].pass)
```